# How to correctly reference a range within a formula in excel?

Tags: excel, range

I am trying to self-contain a formula by creating the range within the formula.
However, I was not able to find how to correctly do this within any documentation.

My current, faulty, function is:

```
=COUNTIF(IF([Event Name]="Approved",[Key],"y"),IF([@[Event Name]]="Reviewed",[@Key],"x"))
```

Which could equally be expressed, outside of a table, as:

```
=COUNTIF(IF(A:A="Approved",B1,"y"),IF(A1="Reviewed",B1,"x"))
```

The created range is spilling out of the first variable of the CountIf function (ie. `=countif(A1,A2..A9,B1)`) causing a spill of the cell itself. Is there anyway I can contain it?

Cheers in advance,

Comment: why extra if() statements in a countif() function when countif() does if anyway?

Comment: We're counting how many times a key exists as both a reviewed and approved state. Otherwise it would count itself or other types of event names.